# Exclude files from hidden directories but not hidden files (under not hidden directories) from find results

Tags: find, directory

Given the following directories structure:

```bsh
$ tree --noreport dir

dir
├── fileA
├── .hiddenfileA
├── .hiddendirA
|   ├── .hiddenfileB
│   ├── fileC
│   └── fileD
└── dirA
    ├── .hiddenfileC
    ├── fileE
    └── fileF
```

The requirement is to make a call to find so that files from hidden directories but not hidden files (under not hidden directories) are excluded from the result.

The expected  return should be something similar to:

```bsh
./.hiddenfileA
./dirA/.hiddenfileC
./dirA/fileE
./dirA/fileF
./fileA
```

Did some research and found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211/170550) information that led me to create the following call to `find`

```bsh
$ find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -print
```

But this solution has the drawback that skips hidden directories **and files**.

Comment: Should a file at the path `some/.dir/here/file` be returned or not?

Comment: @Kusalananda Since it is under a hidden directory it should not be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prune hidden directories and limit the results to files:

```
find . -type d -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f -print
```

As suggested by [jthill](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18837/jthill), you might prefer filtering out directories, which would result in showing files, links etc.:

```
find . -type d -name '.?*' -prune -o ! -type d -print
```

Comment: OCD squishification: `find -type d -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f` -- but you probably want to end with `! -type d` instead of `-type f` so you get symbolic links and other less-usual types

Comment: Thanks for the simplification! I was following the filter from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The command you have is very close to working. 
Use

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/.*/*' -print
```

- The path pattern, `*/.*/*`, looks for a `/.`
  (implying a segment name that begins with **`.`**)
  *followed* (eventually) *by* a `/`
  — so the segment name that begins with **`.`**
  cannot be the last one (the file name); i.e., it must be a directory name.
- `-path` uses filename expansion patterns; a.k.a. globs or wildcards. 
  So you don’t need to put `\` before **`.`**.
- Don’t use `-not` if you want portability to non-GNU systems. 
  The use of `!` to represent “not” is specified by POSIX,
  and works in every version of `find`
  (even BSD, Solaris, etc., and ancient systems).